# How do I remove specific numbers from a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string in PHP:

```
Hopelessly Incredible |SPG:M| 766 STEAM_0:1:20130600 " banned "A
Blatantly Obvious Hacker 740 STEAM_0:1:55386073 " (minutes "0")
(reason "Multi-Hack")
```

The Format of the string is:

```
Name1 Number(0-3 digits) Steam_0:x:xxxx offense (banned/kicked/mute etc) Name2 Number(0-3 digits) Steam_0:x:xxxx time reason
```

My goal is to remove the values `766` and `740` because it is just garbage. Those values can have single, double, and triple digits.

The next step would be to strip `STEAM_0:1:20130600` and `STEAM_0:1:55386073` out of the string and capture it in a new variable. The only constant is `STEAM_0:`, the rest can change.

I am still learning regex but I fear this is a bit complicated for me to do. Some guidance would be most appreciative.

Comment: You really need to detail what the various sections of this string are and what they can contain. Detailing this will take you half-way to constructing the regex (or parsing pattern).

Comment: Use the code notation - `{}` button - for posting code, makes it easier to read. Also, if Steam provides you some API to access that with your PHP, there should be an easier way around that.

Comment: Would the positions of the numbers always be the previous word to STEAM_0? If so, you got the pattern right there with `\d{1,3}(?=\s*STEAM_0)`

Comment: yes Kash it is always in that position

Comment: is it always guaranteed that `STEAM_0` would occur twice in the input?

Comment: No it is not always guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (not good at PHP but this should be close and regexes should work)

```
<?php
$sourcestring='Hopelessly Incredible |SPG:M| 766 STEAM_0:1:20130600 " banned "A Blatantly Obvious Hacker 740 STEAM_0:1:55386073 " (minutes "0") (reason "Multi-Hack")';
$replacedstring = preg_replace('/\d{1,3}(?=\s*STEAM_0)/i','',$sourcestring);
echo $replacedstring;
preg_match_all('/STEAM_0[^\s]+/i',$replacedstring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

Play with the code [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K3YEIH)

---

- Regex `/\d{1,3}(?=\s*STEAM_0)/i` matches numbers occuring before
  `STEAM_0` (positive lookahead) and replaces them with an empty string
- Regex `/STEAM_0[^\s]+/i` matches all `STEAM_0` words (case-insensitive) and prints the
  array of all matches.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat scratch.php
<?php
$s = 'Hopelessly Incredible |SPG:M| 766 STEAM_0:1:20130600 " banned "A Blatantly Obvious Hacker 740 STEAM_0:1:55386073 " (minutes "0") (reason "Multi-Hack")';

$s = preg_replace('@\d+ (STEAM_\d:)@', '\1', $s);
preg_match_all('@(STEAM_\d:\d+:\d+)@', $s, $matches);
var_dump($s, $matches[1]);


$ php scratch.php
string(142) "Hopelessly Incredible |SPG:M| STEAM_0:1:20130600 " banned "A Blatantly Obvious Hacker STEAM_0:1:55386073 " (minutes "0") (reason "Multi-Hack")"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "STEAM_0:1:20130600"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "STEAM_0:1:55386073"
}
```